# SQL Server or Entity Framework outer join query on big tables

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I have three tables; as one of them main table (has 7m records) and have one to many relationships to two child tables.

Table1 (child of tablemain)

```
+----+--------------+-------+------------+ 
| id | tablemain_id | value | updatedate |
+----+--------------+-------+------------+
|  1 |   1111111111 |   500 | 14/04/2020 |
|  2 |   2222222222 |   100 | 15/04/2020 |
|  3 |   2222222222 |   200 | 16/04/2020 |
|  4 |   2222222222 |   300 | 17/04/2020 |
|  5 |   3333333333 |   100 | 18/04/2020 |
|  6 |   3333333333 |   500 | 19/04/2020 |
|  7 |   3333333333 |   600 | 20/04/2020 |
|  8 |   4444444444 |   300 | 21/04/2020 |
|  9 |   4444444444 |   200 | 22/04/2020 |
| 10 |   4444444444 |   900 | 23/04/2020 |
+----+--------------+-------+------------+
```

TableMain (aka Table2)

```
+------------+------------+
|     id     | other data |
+------------+------------+
| 1111111111 | somedata   |
| 2222222222 | somedata   |
| 2222222222 | somedata   |
| 2222222222 | somedata   |
| 3333333333 | somedata   |
| 3333333333 | somedata   |
| 3333333333 | somedata   |
| 4444444444 | somedata   |
| 4444444444 | somedata   |
| 4444444444 | somedata   |
+------------+------------+
```

Table3 (another child of tablemain)

```
+----+--------------+-------+------------+
| id | tablemain_id | price | updatedate |
+----+--------------+-------+------------+
|  1 |   1111111111 |    12 | 20/01/2020 |
|  2 |   2222222222 |    22 | 21/01/2020 |
|  3 |   2222222222 |    21 | 22/01/2020 |
|  4 |   2222222222 |    23 | 23/01/2010 |
|  5 |   3333333333 |    44 | 27/01/2020 |
|  6 |   3333333333 |    41 | 28/01/2020 |
|  7 |   3333333333 |    54 | 29/01/2020 |
|  8 |   5555555555 |    44 | 23/01/2020 |
|  9 |   5555555555 |    22 | 24/01/2020 |
| 10 |   5555555555 |    33 | 25/01/2020 |
+----+--------------+-------+------------+
```

I want to get records from Table1 among **latest** table1.value smaller than 500 **and latest** Table3 pricing date older than 25/01/2020 or null.

My expected result is:

```
+----+--------------+-------+------------+
| id | tablemain_id | value | updatedate |
+----+--------------+-------+------------+
|  4 |   2222222222 |   300 | 17/04/2020 |
| 10 |   4444444444 |   100 | 23/04/2020 |
+----+--------------+-------+------------+
```

Actually I managed get result from this SQL query (SQL queries are fine too) but it is extremely slow! There are roughly 7m rows in `TableMain`.

Here's my query:

```
select *
from 
    (select 
         t1.value as table1value, t1.UpdateTime as T1Update,
         tm.somedata, t3.price, t3.UpdateTime as T3Update
         row_number() over (partition by tablemain_ID order by t3.UpdateTime desc) AS rk2,
         row_number() over (partition by tablemain_ID order by r1.UpdateTime desc) AS rk
     from 
         TableMain tm
     inner join 
         Table1 t1 on tm.ID = t1.TableMain_ID
     full outer join 
         Table3 t3 on tm.ID = TableMain_ID
     group by 
         t1.value, t1.UpdateTime, tm.somedata, t3.price, t3.UpdateTime) tv
where 
    tv.rk = 1  
    and (tv.T3Update < 'somedate' or tv.T3Price is null)
```

Answer (score 0):

Should your result not be 300? 600 is not less than 500?

```
+----+--------------+-------+------------+
| id | tablemain_id | value | updatedate |
+----+--------------+-------+------------+
|  4 |   2222222222 |   300 | 17/04/2020 |
| 10 |   4444444444 |   100 | 23/04/2020 |
+----+--------------+-------+------------+
```

Or do we see example values that are not within the example data? I think it is a bit confusing at the moment because we do not see dates in the example tables but see those dates in the expected result.

Also, your column names do not match what you are asking for. 
In your example query, you filter out T3Price is null but in your request, you say pricing date older than 25-01-2020 or pricing date is null.

Please try to be more accurate in your example so it is easier to see the relationships and requirements.

Comment: also, the results I'm getting from Table1 which my expectation.